# Param views not work,error Column already exists

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying create parameterized views.

```
CREATE VIEW param_views AS
SELECT t.cust_id,
       uniqExact(dep)
FROM table t
WHERE (t.dt >= {date_from:Date32} AND t.dt <= {date_to:Date32})
AND (
    (
        empty({cust_ids:Array(UInt32)})
        AND t.cust_id = t.cust_id
    ) OR (
        notEmpty({cust_ids:Array(UInt32)})
        AND t.cust_id IN ({cust_ids:Array(UInt32)})
    )

)
GROUP BY t.cust_id;
```

But is fail

```
DB::Exception: Column 'cust_ids' already exists: While processing ((dt >= {date_from:Date32}) AND (dt <= {date_to:Date32})) AND ((empty({cust_ids:Array(UInt32)}) AND (cust_id = cust_id)) OR (notEmpty({cust_ids:Array(UInt32)}) AND (cust_id IN ({cust_ids:Array(UInt32)})))). (DUPLICATE_COLUMN) (version 23.3.2.37 (official build))
```

Version CH is 23.3.2.37.

no error occurs if you do this, but then the condition does not work correctly.

```
AND (
    (
        TRUE
    ) OR (
        notEmpty({cust_ids:Array(UInt32)})
        AND t.cust_id IN ({cust_ids:Array(UInt32)})
    )

)
```

Comment: did you try to rename parameter name to `cust_ids_param` to avoid conflict name resolution?

Comment: @Slach, yes, "Column 'cust_ids_param' already exists"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if we replace `empty({cust_ids:Array(UInt32)})` with a `WITH` statement:

```
CREATE VIEW..
WITH empty({cust_ids:Array(UInt64)}) AS _cust_ids
SELECT..
...
WHERE..
AND (
    (
        NOT _cust_ids
        AND t.cust_id = t.cust_id
    ) OR (
        _cust_ids
        AND t.cust_id IN ({cust_ids:Array(UInt32)})
    )

)
```

And, for versions above 23.9, it works in its original form.